# Pip fails installing any package

Tags: python, pip

Pip fails installing any package saying: certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)>. I am working on windows 10.

Here is the whole thing https://pastebin.com/B3pSsehz

I have never encountered this kind of problem, I recently changed pc's and on my previous pc it worked fine with no problems and never gave this error. I don't know if this means anything but I have 2 python installations, one is from the official website and is installed on my B drive and one is from me installing msys2 and it is located on my main C drive.

I tried various things, like updating python, upgrading pip. I've also tried these commands

```
python -m pip install certifi

/Applications/Python\ 3.7/Install\ Certificates.command // which says the command "/Applications/Python\" is not recognized

pip install --upgrade certifi

I also tried:
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
But "import" was not recognized as an internal command

I even tried copying the code of "Install Certificates.command" file I found on the internet and making it a .py file and running it, which did nothing to solve the problem
```

None of these worked and I'm at a loss, please help.

Comment: Where exactly did you try `/Applications/Python\ 3.7/Install\ Certificates.command`? The backslashes tell the shell that the next space is part of the file name ... but if you aren't using the shell you need something different (try without the backslashes?)

Comment: I just pasted it in the command prompt, also I don't really understand how should the command look in your opinion?

Comment: Try using your shell's tab completion to get the proper path.